# Different handling of Short values in VB6 and VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, types, vb6

I was upgrading some VB6 code to VB.NET recently. One odd issue that came up is a difference in the `short` data types.

The original VB6 code has the following line:

```
foobar(&H8589)
```

where `foobar` is a function that accepts one `short` argument. The above code worked fine in VB6. The purpose is to pass two bytes to this function and `short` seemed to be a fitting data type, as it represents 2 bytes.

Upon upgrading, the code suddenly returns the error `Constant value not representable in type 'Short'.` So I read about this data type in [MSDN, where it says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tb7bdw6.aspx):

> Holds signed 16-bit (2-byte) integers that range in value from -32,768 through 32,767.

So let's convert `0x8589` to DEC. Turns up as `-31,351` which is well within the boundary set by the type. Now, the odd thing is: When I call the function using the DEC value (`foobar(-31351)`) - it works!

So you might ask why I won't just use the DEC value. Well, using HEX has the advantage that everyone looking at the code immediately knows what bytes are passed, which is important in this case.

So: Why can't I use the HEX representation? Is this difference documented somewhere? Is there a way I could use the HEX code without changing the function (eg. to accept two `Byte` arguments)?

Comment: H8589 converts to 34185 value in integer. That is beyond the short data type boundary which is why you are getting error.

Comment: It sounds like you want an unsigned short.

Comment: @Harsh But converted with a width of 2 bytes, it results in `-31351`. This seems to be what VB6 was doing internally. I wonder why it was changed - the upgrade engine didn't even leave a comment, though is is definitively an incompatibility.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, `UShort` solves this problem :-) .

Comment: You can also use a literal type specifier of `S` to indicate a short:  `foobar(&H8589S)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a negative hex int16 constant, precede the value with FFFF. It seems that hex constants are int32 (at least) in vb.net.

```
  dim w as int16
  w = &HFFFF8589
```

Comment: You can also use a type specifier character of `S`: `Dim w As Int16 = &H8589S`